# c# adding 5 text boxes with the sixth showing the result

Tags: c#

I am trying to find the sum of 5 text boxes in which the user inputs the data and outputs at the sixth text box.

I keep getting an error saying that the values aren't assigned yet I don't know how to assign them.

This is my code so far:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int value1 = 0;
        int value2 = 0;
        int value3 = 0;
        int value4 = 0;
        int value5 = 0;
        int result = 0;

        if (int.TryParse(textBox4.Text, out value1) & int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out value2))

        {
            result = value1 + value2;
            textBox21.Text = result.ToString();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Edit your question to add exact error msg and which line it happen will help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to C#! Here's a bit of aid for your first time:

1. The default value of `int` is zero so you don't have to set it.
2. You have used the unary operator of `&` instead of the binary `&&`. This means the 'if' will still evaluate the second condition even if the first one returns false. If that is your desire, that works.
3. If `textbox2` or `textbox4` is empty, `result` remains zero but `textbox21.Text` will remain unset. If you have other logic elsewhere we don't see, this may be causing your problem.

You have the right idea using TryParse and I'd suggest continuing to use it, as Convert will throw exceptions if the value is either null or using an improper format. If you don't handle the exceptions, your program will crash (the typical solution is to wrap your conversion code in a try/catch block). If you want to post the exact error text you're receiving we can help further if needed.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int value1 = 0;
    int value2 = 0;
    int value3 = 0;
    int value4 = 0;
    int value5 = 0;
    int result = 0;

    if (int32.TryParse(textBox4.Text, out value1) & int32.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out value2))

    {
        result = value1 + value2;
        textBox21.Text = result.ToString();
    }

}
```

you can also do it simpler like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int value1 = 0;
    int value2 = 0;
    int value3 = 0;
    int value4 = 0;
    int value5 = 0;
    int result = 0;

    value1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text);
    value2 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);

    result = value1 + value2;
    textBox21.Text = result.ToString();
}
```

Comment: should i add the other values to the if statement and it shall assign them to each value?

Comment: it's up to you.

Comment: yeah since i am trying to add all values